# Why my pub sub message acknowledged? -> Data loss

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a cloud function which is called Pub/Sub. It should ACK the message only when it has been correctly processed.

I see in my logs a memory failure, then a message 'Finished with status: ok'.
[image: Google Cloud Logs]

And the message is acknowledged and removed from my Pub / Sub topic!

Reproducer:

```py
import base64
import requests

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    """ Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
        Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    # let's say that important stuff is done at the line below 
    # which should be retried in case of failure
    r = requests.get('https://zoom.us/client/latest/zoomusInstallerFull.pkg')
    print(pubsub_message)
```

Comment: do you have detail in the error? Are you sure that is the same invocation ID?*

Comment: I confirm that it is the same execution id. You can see a part of this execution id in the screenshot.
No details are provided (however, I understand the root cause).

Answer (score 0):

If the Google Cloud Function is going to be executed, it follows that the subject has already **received the ack message.**

The messages will receive an ACK if your function successfully completes by returning a resolved promise. PubSub will retry the message if the function throws an error or returns a denied promise.

Therefore, to prevent looping, you must build a retry method that will try a predetermined number of times and then quit. This is necessary if your Cloud Function was unable to process the received message.

Now, in accordance with the previous comment, try allowing `retry on failure` when an `executionID` is connected to the request that resulted in error. When a retriable exception is raised, this enables function execution to be retried.

Reviewing for the exact error message that is showing in Cloud Functions which is “Function invocation was interrupted. Error: function terminated”, tt would be advised to check the logs for termination-related information.

Here is further troubleshooting information from the [Logging section](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging). Setting up logs to aid in problem-solving can lead to more issues.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. The function crash and the pub sub message is neither redelivered nor put in a dead-letter as it is unfortunately acked.